# New file keeps showing up in git even though added to gitignore

Tags: git

I need to ignore a file with git. Ive added an entry to my gitignore and created a file at the same path and name but its still showing up as a new file in git.

Ive tried this but it doesn't work:

```
git rm -rf --cached filepath/filename
```

The message I get is:

```
fatal: pathspec 'filepath/filename' did not match any files
```

If I run theses then I can a huge number of changes in git so I'm scared to commit this change.

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
```

UPDATE 
This is what ive added to my gitignore

```
sites/default/settings.local.php
```

And this is the message in git:

```
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    sites/default/settings.local.php

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Comment: Can you show your `.gitignore` and the results of `git status`?

Comment: @EdwardThomson Ive updated my question.

Comment: You're using `.gitignore` - with a leading dot - correct?  Not just a file called `gitignore`?

Comment: Yes the file had a leading dot

Answer (score 0):

In git, a file already added to the history will not be ignored even if you add it to .gitignore

If you want it to go away you will need to remove from history following this guide:
https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/

Note: may be a good idea to do a test on a copy of your git repo first.

Comment: I dont think its already been added. I pulled down the repo today and the file wasnt there.

Comment: That is strange, how about adding /sites/default/settings.local.php  to your .gitignore? notice the '/' at the begining.